# Google Cloud machine Network Restart flushes iptables

Tags: google-cloud-platform, centos7

I'm facing some issue with some machines that I currently have over google Gloud as NAT Gateways. This machines also act as firewalls. Lately this machines have been restarted its network service but also my iptables rules have been flushed.

I currently have a service configured with systemctl as a service with autostart option that must always be up and running.

During last weekend this rules have been flushed. The machine has not been restarted.

Is there any place where do I can Indicate where the "standart" iptables rules must not be applied in case of network restart.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [iptables-persistent](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#natgateway) If you want these settings to persist across future reboots.

To configure iptables-persistent, you need to tell it about your current iptables ruleset.

To accomplish follow as below:

```
iptables-save >/etc/iptables/rules.v4
ip6tables-save >/etc/iptables/rules.v6
```

Equivalently, the iptables-persistent package also provided as following:

```
dpkg-reconfigure iptables-persistent
```

(Answer 'yes' when asking to save the rules)

The iptables-persistent must be started or restarted for it to have an effect on the live configuration.

If the rulesets were constructed from the current live configuration then there is no immediate need for iptables-persistent to do anything, because the stored and live configurations are already in agreement.
The iptables-persistent service automatically starts when the system is rebooted.
You will need to explicitly start the service if you provide the rulesets by some other means:

```
service iptables-persistent start
```